# Как в VBA применять WorksheetFunction к части (отрезку или прямоугольной подобласти) массива?

Tags: массивы, excel, vba

Предположим, задан одномерный или двумерный массив, с ним можно работать функциями листов. Например, следующим образом.

```
Dim x(3)
x(0) = 1
x(1) = 5
x(2) = -1
x(3) = 3
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(x)
MsgBox y
```

А что делать, если нужно подобным образом обращаться к различным отрезкам массива? Например, в цикле считать минимум в меняющихся пределах части массива?

Создавать для этого собственную функцию - напрягать интерпретатор частым разбором всё тех же строк VBA-кода, что весьма непроизводительно.

Аналогичный вопрос в отношении любой прямоугольной части двумерного массива.

*Добавлено к сообщению позднее.*

Для теста скорости исходный код упрощён.

```
    'Начало скрипта
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("K1").Value = "" Then
    Range("K1").Value = "delete"
    Range("L1").Value = Now()
    Range("L1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    Range("B:B").Clear
    Range("L2").ClearContents
    n = Range("C1").Value
    m = Range("D1").Value
    iMethod = Range("E1").Value
    A = Range("A1:A" & n)
    Dim b
    ReDim b(1 To n, 1 To 1)
    If iMethod = 1 Then
        For i = 1 To n
            If i <= m Then
                b(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("A1:A" & i + m))
            ElseIf i > n - m Then
                b(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("A" & i - m & ":A" & n))
            Else
                b(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("A" & i - m & ":A" & i + m))
            End If
        Next
        Range("B1:B" & n).Value = b
    ElseIf iMethod = 2 Then
        For i = 1 To n
            If i <= m Then
                b(i, 1) = "=MIN(A1:A" & i + m & ")"
            ElseIf i > n - m Then
                b(i, 1) = "=MIN(A" & i - m & ":A" & n & ")"
            Else
                b(i, 1) = "=MIN(A" & i - m & ":A" & i + m & ")"
            End If
        Next
        Range("B1:B" & n).Formula = b
        b = Range("B1:B" & n).Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Under construction."
    End If
    Range("L2").Value = Now()
    Range("L2").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
End If
```

End Sub
'Конец скрипта

Клетки A1:A1000000 заполнены для теста случайными числами от 1 до 100000 (сохранены "как значения", чтобы не тратилось время на новую генерацию при каждом неосторожном чихе), в клетку C1 помещено число 1000000, в клетку D1 - число 500, в клетку E1 - одно из чисел 1 или 2 (для двух тестов поочерёдно), в клетку K1 - слово "delete" (запуск скрипта по её очищению). При E1=1 тест работал больше 2 минут, при E1=2 - порядка минуты.

Comment: Если работать именно функцией листа, то можно так: отключаем обновление экрана, создаём, если отсутствует, лист (возможно, скрытый) для расчётов, копируем массив на лист (нужен двумерный массив, есссно), пересчитываем нужный поддиапазон, применяем функцию, чистим либо удаляем лист. Иных способов я как-то не вижу.

Comment: PS. Если массив одномерный - при копировании на лист нужно указать горизонтальный диапазон. PPS. Работать есссно удобнее в R1C1.

Comment: Такое решение мне известно. Но эту операцию нужно выполнить не один раз, а в цикле много раз для различных пределов, поэтому ищу что-то более попроизводительнее. Поиском удалось найти только выделение целой строки или столбца из двумерного массива методом Index. Насколько личный опыт даёт основания полагать, что нет какого-то подобного производительного решения?

Comment: В любом случае работа чисто на VBA будет производительнее, чем с листом. Нужно искать именно максимальное значение?

Comment: @Akina
Работа на VBA плюс многократный проход в цикле интерпретатора, который раз за разом анализирует одни и те же строки кода, часто даёт результат по производительности заметно хуже, чем какая-то одна строка, за выполнением которой стоят всё те же алгоритмические шаги, но без многократного анализа интерпретатором. Вопрос возник в связи с конкретным применением скользящих минимумов и максимумов, но, конечно, хочется научиться решать и подобные задачи.

Comment: Если надо всё время искать по одному и тому же массиву - я бы всё же вывалил массив на скрытый лист, а потом в одной ячейке менял формулу и забирал результат. То есть получается на старте - создание и размещение данных на скрытом листе, а в коде по мере надобности всего 2 строчки.

Comment: @Akina Это намного хуже даже, чем в моём втором варианте (при E1=2): хотя бы формулы надо не по одной выводить, а сразу массив на лист.

Comment: @Akina Даже если массив на миллион ячеек таскать частями по тысячу ячеек за раз, скорость падает чуть ли не втрое в сравнении с полной передачей миллиона (только что опробовано, теплилась у меня надежда, что экономии можно будет достичь за счёт баланса между количеством таких трансферов и объёмом формул в Excel, который по-своему умеет тормозить работу). А через одну ячейку Excel на описанных данных попросту подвисает и к жизни не возвращается вовсе. У меня уже есть опыт, в результате которого пришлось отказаться от работы через одну ячейку. Даже простые вещи долго работали.

Answer (score 0):

Использование функций листа в коде - такая операция медленнее, чем работа в собственных VBA-дебрях. Подобные попытки ускорить вычисления могут привести  к противоположному результату.

Для решения конкретной задачи нужно видеть... конкретную задачу :)

В общем виде:

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr_
    
    arr_ = Range("A2:D7").Value
    
    With Application
        Debug.Print .Min(.Index(arr_, 4, 0)) ' минимальное в "строке" массива
        Debug.Print .Sum(.Index(arr_, 0, 2)) ' сумма в "столбце" массива
    End With
End Sub
```

Для прямоугольной области решения с помощью функций листа у меня нет.

Часто решение проблем находится в миксованном решении - формулы на листе + VBA

Comment: Добавлен упрощённый вид кода, скорость которого хотелось бы улучшить. Да, мне тоже кажется, что миксованное решение лучше всего, поэтому и родился план пользоваться функциями листа на массиве VBA, но непонятно, как (и можно ли) скормить им не весь массив, а лишь заданный его фрагмент.

Comment: Нет. О миксованном решении - это когда мухи отдельно от котлет - функции в формулах на листе, а не в VBA

Comment: Ну это примерно так, как у меня во втором варианте (при E1=2), но даже для одного просчёта (а мне требуется не один) потребовалось больше минуты, а иногда даже вообще зависает.

Answer (score 0):

О добавленном в вопрос коде.

Не прописан диапазон реагирования на изменения на листе. Надо добавить:

```
If Application.Intersect(Range("K1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Грубая ошибка - нет отключения событий на время работы макроса. Событие `Worksheet_Change`срабатывает каждый раз при изменении в ячейках. В показанном примере это почти не сказывается на производительности, т.к. стоит заглушка в `K1` (при этом изменения все равно вызывают проверку условия), но если игнорировать такую "мелочь", можно получить большие тормоза, зацикливания... В общем, чтобы избежать головной боли в будущем, события нужно отключать, если работа кода предполагает работу с листом:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Если в коде работы с листом много, нужно отключать обновление экрана, т.к. перерисовка картинки медленная:

```
Application: .ScreenUpdating = False
```

VBA - язык со строгой типизацией. Не нужно забывать декларировать все используемые переменные.

`Worksheet_Change` - событие листа и его желательно не замусоривать лишними операциями. Тем более, когда в коде есть переменные - при любом изменении на листе срабатывает событие и сразу под все переменные выделяется память. А так как у Вас переменным не присвоены типы (все типа *Variant*), то объем памяти откусывается под тип, занимающий наибольший кусок оперативки.

Событие сработало и передало управление макросу в общем модуле:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.Intersect(Range("K1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .EnableEvents = False: End With
    Range("L1").Value = Now()

    Call test

    Range("L2").Value = Now()
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True: End With
End Sub
```

А еще лучше - поменьше использовать события и запускать обработку иным способом(например, повесить макрос на кнопку).

Теперь о работе двух вариантов. Если исключить выгрузку на лист после циклов, второй вариант отрабатывает меньше секунды. Т.е. его основная нагрузка - запись на лист формул. В первом варианте наоборот - медленная запись в массив из-за вычислений функций.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно посчитать скользящий минимум, среднее, сумму, то для высокой производительности лучше использовать инкрементальный подход, т.е. не считать каждый раз все "окно", а удалять самый старый элемент и добавлять самый новый. Как-то так:

```
Function generate(n)
    ReDim a(n)
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        a(i) = CInt(Rnd * 10000)
    Next
    generate = a
End Function


Sub rolling_min(a)
    Min = a(LBound(a))
    For i = LBound(a) + 1 To UBound(a)
        If a(i) < Min Then
            Min = a(i)
        End If
'        Debug.Print a(i), Min
    Next
End Sub

Sub rolling_avg(a, winsize)
    cnt = 1
    Sum = 0
    first = 0
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If cnt < winsize Then
            Sum = Sum + a(i)
'            Debug.Print a(i), "-"
        Else
            Sum = Sum - first + a(i)
            first = a(i - winsize + 1)
'            Debug.Print a(i), Sum / winsize
        End If
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next
End Sub


Sub test1()
    t = Timer
    n = 10 ^ 8
    a = generate(n)
    Debug.Print "a", "rolling_min"
    rolling_min a
    Debug.Print "a", "rolling_avg"
    rolling_avg a, 3
    Debug.Print "Элементов: ", n, "время выполнения,c = ", Timer - t
End Sub
```

```
a             rolling_min
a             rolling_avg
Элементов:     100000000    время выполнения,c =         30,79297
```

В коде генерится 100 млн элементов и считаются скользящий минимум и скользящее среднее (без вывода на экран - закомментировано) за 0,5 минуты.

Comment: Инкрементальный подход, конечно, присутствует в моём плане B, но так просто это не работает, код намногого сложнее.